# SSRS report tables mutiple lines not showing

Tags: reporting-services, report, x++, erp, dynamics-365-operations

I am doing Microsoft Dynmics D365 report layout. I have a table in my report that need to show the lines from the table in MS Dynamic D365. Which have only 2 lines.

D365 frontend system:

[image]

In the report layout, it is only showing the first line and the second line is not showing.

Report layout first line only showing:

[image]

I want the 2 lines to be showed in the report. I am not sure if my coding is not right or the row group that I am grouping in the report design. Please help me please. Apperciated.

here is my code in the dp class to get the table lines:

```
PurchPurchaseOrderTmp.MGAItemLabelName = PurchExtendedMaster.ExtName;

PurchPurchaseOrderTmp.MGAColValue1 = PurchExtended.ColValue1;
PurchPurchaseOrderTmp.MGAColValue2 = PurchExtended.ColValue2;
PurchPurchaseOrderTmp.MGAColValue3 = PurchExtended.ColValue3;
PurchPurchaseOrderTmp.MGAColValue4 = PurchExtended.ColValue4;
PurchPurchaseOrderTmp.MGALabelId = PurchExtended.LabelId;
//PurchPurchaseOrderTmp.MGALabelIdString += int2Str(PurchExtended.LabelVersion);
         
if (PurchPurchaseOrderTmp.MGAItemLabelName != "") {
    PurchPurchaseOrderTmp.MGALabelIdString = strFmt("%1-%2", 
    PurchExtended.LabelId, int2Str(PurchExtended.LabelVersion));
} 
else {
    PurchPurchaseOrderTmp.MGALabelIdString = "";
}
```

Here is my report design row grouping:

[image: report design]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is not really an answer at the moment as I can't see enough to be certain but...

Looking at the report design, it 'appears' that you don't have anything in the details row(s). The details group rows have been reduced in height so I'm guessing there is nothing in there.

That means that the text boxes below this must be in a group header or footer which is why they will only appear once.

The best way to get your head round this is to dump all the data from your dataset into a simple flat table, then see what you want repeating.

For exmaple, it looks like `Label ID` (`MGAItemLabelName` ?) should only be shown once, so there needs to be a group for that - which it looks like you have.

Then within that label name group, you have two rows of data that you want to show, so these must be at a lower level than their parent group. That might be the details row group, or another row group between the header and details depending on your needs.

The details row group typically contains fields that you want to show every instance of and that does not have any subordinate/child data.

Comment: Hey Thanks for the comment. I try group using a seqence Number 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, in whicg I have that field in the table. But still I cannot loop the date and still having one line instead expecting to have 2 lines. Please help any more solution or tips that you can give me. Please help me!!